# Array Return In Blank

Tags: php, ajax

i have solve the error from the code but now the array it return in blank any idea of the problem can some one give a little hand on it please
the code is

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$res=mysql_query("SELECT user_level FROM users where user=".$_SESSION['user']);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
echo $rows['user_level'];

// close while loop 
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: It's possible that `$res` is empty. If that's the case it would never get into the while loop. Try echoing something right before the die to see if that is part of the problem.

Comment: i have try to make an echo before die and nothing i have try with an existing row like user_name and the row its not empty but nothing return

Comment: well i put the peace of code you tell me and nothing change

Answer (score 0):

Do the same thing like this way:

```
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
echo $sql = "SELECT user_level FROM users where user='".$user."'";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($res);
if($count > 0){
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        echo $rows['user_level'];
        // close while loop 
    }
    die();
}else{
    echo 'No rows.';
}
```

Comment: Tank You For The Help it s strange wen i execute the code it return no rows but i have the row there any idea?

Comment: @HelderDaSilveiraVentura put: `echo "SELECT user_level FROM users where user='".$user."'";` in your code and paste the result of that echo right into MySQL and see if you get the result you think you should.

Comment: @HelderDaSilveiraVentura, I update my answer, echo the `$sql`. please do what `Keeleon` say.